# Chrome API / WebExtensions for opening textfield in external editor

Tags: google-chrome, file-io, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I was using Vimperator so far that supported the keybinding `C-i` to open up Emacs (or whatever editor) so you can continue writing your text there. That was accomplished by creating a temporary file, putting the text you had so far in there, invoking the editor with that file as an argument and when the editor process died it would read the contents of the temporary file back into the textbox. Is that possible in Chrome or in Firefox's WebExtensions API, and if so how?

Comment: likely not possible. but the question is offtopic as its about finding a tool, not programming. try superuser forum.

Comment: In order for this to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, it needs to be reworded to be clearly about how to write an extension to do what you want. Right now, it sounds more like you are a user that is looking for an extension which does what you desire. I actually could read this both ways. Given that you are asking on SO, I initially read it as asking about programming. Thus, I am not voting to close. Please [edit] the question to be more clear, either way.

Comment: I outlined how it used to be possible to solve this problem with the previous APIs. I thought it was clear that my intention was to put together an extension to do this myself, but apparently not. Could you review that the intent is clear now?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with the native messaging API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

I created a simple demo extension a while back that does a very limited verstion of what you're asking about here: https://github.com/aswan/connectNative-example